Where is the legend of Sage Agastya crossing Vindhya range found?
Did he aryanize south India? What were its implications? Where is the incident found?

I've answered but here's a related answer with references from the Skanda Purana which may also interest you. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20674/story-of-agastya-rishi-correcting-balance-of-the-earth

Short Answer:
The incident of Agastya crossing over Mount Vindhya is found in both Mahabharata as well as Valmiki Ramayana.
In the past, Agastya Muni made the Dravida provinces livable by protecting humans from Rakshasas that had taken over. This is told by the sage Suteekshna to Lord Ram and Lakshman in Ramayana.
Agastya did not newly introduce Vedic culture in Dravida-desha but only re-established it at a certain point in history.
This is similar to how Lord Krishna had appeared to re-establish dharma in Kurukshetra (dharma-samsthāpanārthāya
sambhavāmi yuge yuge..Gita 4.8).
Long Answer:
Mahabharata Tirtha-yatra Parva Chapter 399
युधिष्ठिर उवाच ।
किमर्थं सहसा विन्ध्यः प्रवृद्धः क्रोधमूर्छितः ।
एतदिच्छाम्यहं श्रोतुं विस्तरेण महामुने ॥ १ ॥


Yudhishthira asked, “O great sage! Why was Vindhya angered and why did
he suddenly begin to grow? I wish to hear about this in great detail."

लोमश उवाच ।
अद्रिराजं महाशैलं मरुं कनकपर्वतम् ।
उदयास्तमये भानुः प्रदक्षिणमवर्तत ॥ २ ॥


‘Lomasha replied, At the time of rising and at the time of setting,
the sun used to circumambulate the great mountain Meru, the golden
king of mountains.

तं तु दृष्ट्वा तथा विन्ध्यः शैलः सूर्यमथाब्रवीत् ।
यथा हि मेरुर्भवता नित्यशः परिगम्यते ।
प्रदक्षिणं च क्रियते मामेवं कुरु भास्कर ॥ ३ ॥


On seeing this, Mount Vindhya told Surya, ‘O Bhaskara! You always go
around Meru. Circumambulate me in the same way.’

एवमुक्तस्ततः सूर्यः शैलेन्द्रं प्रत्यभाषत ।
नाहमात्मेच्छया शैल करोम्येनं प्रदक्षिणम् ।
एष मार्गः प्रदिष्टो मे येनेदं निर्मितं जगत् ॥ ४ ॥


Having been thus addressed, Surya replied to the king of the
mountains, ‘O mountain! I do not circumambulate him out of my own
desires. He who created the universe has assigned this path for me.’

एवमुक्तस्ततः क्रोधात्प्रवृद्धः सहसाचलः ।
सूर्याचन्द्रमसोर्मार्गं रोद्धुमिच्छन्परंतप ॥ ५ ॥


Having been thus addressed, the mountain was angered and suddenly
began to increase. O scorcher of enemies! He sought to obstruct the
paths of the sun and the moon.

ततो देवाः सहिताः सर्व एव सेन्द्राः समागम्य महाद्रिराजम् ।
निवारयामासुरुपायतस्तं न च स्म तेषां वचनं चकार ॥ ६ ॥


Then all the gods assembled and, with Indra, went to Vindhya, the
great king of the mountains. They tried to restrain him from what he
was doing, but he paid no attention to their words.

अथाभिजग्मुर्मुनिमाश्रमस्थं तपस्विनं धर्मभृतां वरिष्ठम् ।
अगस्त्यमत्यद्भुतवीर्यदीप्तं तं चार्थमूचुः सहिताः सुरास्ते ॥ ७ ॥


Then the gods went to the sage Agastya, the ascetic who was supreme
among those who followed dharma and radiant in his valor, in his
hermitage. The gods told him everything.

देवा ऊचुः । सूर्याचन्द्रमसोर्मार्गं नक्षत्राणां गतिं तथा । शैलराजो
वृणोत्येष विन्ध्यः क्रोधवशानुगः ॥ ८ ॥


The gods said, ‘Consumed and overcome by anger, Vindhya, king of the
mountains, is obstructing the paths of the sun, the moon and the
nakshatras.

तं निवारयितुं शक्तो नान्यः कश्चिद्द्विजोत्तम ।
ऋते त्वां हि महाभाग तस्मादेनं निवारय ॥ ९ ॥


O supreme among brahmanas! No one except you is capable of restraining
him. O immensely fortunate one! Therefore, restrain him.'

लोमश उवाच ।
तच्छ्रुत्वा वचनं विप्रः सुराणां शैलमभ्यगात् ।
सोऽभिगम्याब्रवीद्विन्ध्यं सदारः समुपस्थितः ॥ १० ॥


On hearing the words of the gods, the brahmana went to the mountain.
He went to Vindhya with his wife and told him.

मार्गमिच्छाम्यहं दत्तं भवता पर्वतोत्तम ।
दक्षिणामभिगन्तास्मि दिशं कार्येण केनचित् ॥ ११ ॥


‘O supreme among mountains! I wish that you should create a path for
me. I have to go in a southern direction for some work.'

यावदागमनं मह्यं तावत्त्वं प्रतिपालय ।
निवृत्ते मयि शैलेन्द्र ततो वर्धस्व कामतः ॥ १२ ॥


'O Indra among mountains! Restrain yourself until I return from there
and you can then grow as much as you wish.’

एवं स समयं कृत्वा विन्ध्येनामित्रकर्शन ।
अद्यापि दक्षिणाद्देशाद्वारुणिर्न निवर्तते ॥ १३ ॥


O destroyer of enemies! Having made this agreement with Vindhya,
Varuna’s son went towards the southern direction and has not returned
till this day.

एतत्ते सर्वमाख्यातं यथा विन्ध्यो न वर्धते ।
अगस्त्यस्य प्रभावेन यन्मां त्वं परिपृच्छसि ॥ १४ ॥


Just as you asked me to, I have told you everything about why Vindhya
does not increase, because of Agastya’s powers.

Sri Valmiki Ramayana Aranya-Kanda Chapter 11
At a certain point in time, the southern provinces had become unlivable due to being taken over by Rakshasas such as Vaataapi and Ilvala who ate human flesh.
निगृह्य तरसा मृत्युम् लोकानाम् हित काम्यया |
दक्षिणा दिक् कृता येन शरण्या पुण्य कर्मणा ||


He who impeding death by his yogic might and wishing well-being for
worlds made this southern extent a liveable province by his pious
deeds, his hermitage is this.

तस्य इदम् आश्रम पदम् प्रभावाद् यस्य राक्षसैः |
दिक् इयम् दक्षिणा त्रासाद् दृश्यते न उपभुज्यते ||


Under whose influence the demons behold this southern quarter
appallingly, and they do not even venture to live here, such a sage
Agastya's hermitage is this.

यदा प्रभृति च आक्रान्ता दिग् इयम् पुण्य कर्मणा |
तदा प्रभृति निर् वैराः प्रशान्ता रजनी चराः || 

नाम्ना च इयम् भगवतो दक्षिणा दिक् प्रदक्षिणा |
प्रथिता त्रिषु लोकेषु दुर्धर्षा क्रूर कर्मभिः ||


And from when that pious deeded Agastya took possession of this
quarter [Dravida-Desha], from then on, the night walkers are calmed down and remained
without feud.

नाम्ना च इयम् भगवतो दक्षिणा दिक् प्रदक्षिणा |
प्रथिता त्रिषु लोकेषु दुर्धर्षा क्रूर कर्मभिः ||


This very worthy southern quarter is known in the name of that godly
saint Agastya and this remained unattackable to the demons with cruel
deeds.

The lowering of Mount Vindhya by Agastya Muni to balance the solar and lunar movement, seasons' revolve, Vedic calendars etc. is also found in the below verse.
मार्गम् निरोद्धुम् सततम् भास्करस्य अचल उत्तमः |
संदेशम् पालयन् तस्य विंध्य शैलो न वर्धते || ४-११-८५
अयम् दीर्घ आयुषः तस्य लोके विश्रुत कर्मणः |
अगस्त्यस्य आश्रमः श्रीमान् विनीत मृग सेवितः || ४-११-८६


"Complying which sage's directive Mount Vindhya ceased to heighten in
order not to obstruct the path of the sun, such sage's hermitage is
this who is renowned in the world by his deeds and whose longevity is
inestimable, hence this glorious hermitage is adored by well-behaved
animals and humans as well. [4-11-85, 86]
The name Agastya is derived from a famous act of this Sage. Mount Meru
is the highest peak on earth. By its nature it grows day by day, and
stands first to be saluted by the rising sun in east every day.
Jealous of this Mount Meru, Mount Vindhya started to rise to exceed the
height of Mount Meru, thus obstructing the sun's path. Then the day
changed for night and the travel of Sun and Moon, the performance of
Vedic rituals, which are bound by the solar lunar movement, went
topsy-turvy. Then the gods prayed Agastya to do something to decrease
the height of Mount Meru. Agastya and his wife then were coming to Mount
Vindhya and seeing its height, he requested Mount Vindhya, "Oh, Mountain
King Vindhya, myself and my wife are going southward, and we are not
able to climb this much height... kindly lower yourself, so that we
old people climb you and go to the other side..." Mount Vindhya being an
ardent worshipper of sages and saints immediately lowered his height
to the ground level, so that the old couple need not climb but just
walk over him. Agastya and his wife on coming to the southern side of
the mountain again requested Mount Vindhya to be at this height only,
for they will be returning soon to north. Mount Vindhya readily agreed
for that also, and it is lying like that even today. Because Agastya
did not return to north on coming to south Mount Vindhya is still
believed to be at ground level. Thus the solar and lunar movement,
seasons' revolve, Vedic calendars etc. are again put to normalcy. Thus
the name Agastya, aga stha mountain, stopper, agam sthaasyati or,
stabhnaati iti agastyaH. He played an important role in uplifting
southern regions of India, namely Dravidian cultures. Hid wife is
Lopaamudra, the saintly lady will be quoted in Lalitha Sahasra
Naamaavali. The thousand name of Mother Universe.

Current Manu was a Dravida king
The term Draviḍa refers to the southern provinces of India whereas ārya means a civilized person i.e., one who is advanced in spiritual consciousness.
Those residing in the Southern provinces of India are followers of the Vedas during every millennium of Manu as seen in the below verse from Shrimad Bhagavatam 9.1.2-3 where King Satyavrata from Dravida-desa rose to the position of the present Vaivasvata Manu by the grace of Lord Vishnu.
योऽसौ सत्यव्रतो नाम राजर्षिर्द्रविडेश्वर: ।
ज्ञानं योऽतीतकल्पान्ते लेभे पुरुषसेवया ॥ २ ॥
स वै विवस्वत: पुत्रो मनुरासीदिति श्रुतम् ।
त्वत्तस्तस्य सुता:प्रोक्ता इक्ष्वाकुप्रमुखा नृपा: ॥ ३ ॥


Satyavrata, the saintly king of Draviḍadeśa who received spiritual
knowledge at the end of the last millennium by the grace of the
Supreme, later became Vaivasvata Manu, the son of Vivasvān, in the
next manvantara [period of Manu]. I have received this knowledge from
you. I also understand that such kings as Ikṣvāku were his sons, as
you have already explained.


please delete "Agastya Muni is well-known in southern India because of his heroic deeds in the past to make Dravida provinces livable once again after protecting humans from the Rakshasas who had taken over. He did not newly introduce Vedic culture in Dravida-desha but only re-established it.".  This is a political statement @harihara

ramayana implies that there were NO HUMANS in peninsular India during the time of Rama's war - Rama could only assemble monkeys and bears on the way to Lanka.  your statement has nothing to do with Hinduism and I find it very offensive. @harihara

Who was King Satyavrata in his previous birth when he became Manu during the present Vaivasvata Manvantara when Ramayana happened? It shows how old Dravida is. Please read the answer carefully before feeling offended for no reason.
